# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), не могу присвоить два значения двум разным переменным

Tags: python, словари, for, переменные

Как присвоить переменной i значения словаря, а j ключи словаря поочерёдно в for?
Моя попытка это сделать:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://swapi.dev/api'
response = requests.get(url).json()
people_api = response['people']
planets_api = response['planets']
starships_api = response['starships']

speed_of_starships = {}


def starships(url):
    response_starships = requests.get(url).json()
    for i in range(0, 4):
        name = response_starships['results'][i]['name']
        max_atmosphering_speed = response_starships['results'][i]['max_atmosphering_speed']

        speed_of_starships[name] = max_atmosphering_speed
    for i, j in speed_of_starships.values(), speed_of_starships:
        if i == 'n/a':
            del speed_of_starships[j]
        else:
            print(speed_of_starships)
            print(i, j)
    for i in speed_of_starships:
        answer = max(speed_of_starships, key=speed_of_starships.get)


starships(starships_api)
```

Ошибка которая выдается:

```
    for i, j in speed_of_starships.values(), speed_of_starships:
        ^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: `for i, j in zip(speed_of_starships.values(), speed_of_starships):`

Comment: `for j, i in speed_of_starships.items():`

Comment: @maestro, Спасибо!